# Error on removed index creating a database using a VS 2017 database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a Database project I created in VS 2017. I've changed it substantially including moving columns to different tables, etc.

I then deleted the bin & obj folders. I also went to C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13, killed sqlserver.exe in the running processes, and then deleted all files in that folder.

And I am still getting the following when I build:

```
------ Build started: Project: Database1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        Loading project references...
        Loading project files...
        Building the project model and resolving object interdependencies...
        Validating the project model...
        Writing model to C:\git\Store\Database1\obj\Debug\Model.xml...
        Database1 -> C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.dll
        Database1 -> C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.dacpac
------ Deploy started: Project: Database1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72023: The database containment option has been changed to None.  This may result in deployment failure if the state of the database is not compliant with this containment level.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Organization].[BillingId] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Person].[CompanyName] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Person].[IsBilling] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Person].[IsEnabled] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[BillingErrorDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[BillingMode] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[BillingStatus] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[ChargeToken] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[DeactivateDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[DeleteDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[Discount] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[NextBaseBillingDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[NextOverageBillingDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Warning:  SQL72015: The column [dbo].[Subscription].[ShutoffDate] is being dropped, data loss could occur.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Error:  SQL72031: This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[Subscription].[ApiKey1] are blocked by [dbo].[Subscription].[IX_Subscription_ApiKey]'s dependency in the target database.
C:\git\Store\Database1\bin\Debug\Database1.sql: Error:  Deploy72002: Plan verification encountered errors; deployment cannot continue.
Done building project "Database1.sqlproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

There no longer is an IX_Subscription_ApiKey (it is replaced with IX_Subscription_ApiKey1).

The subscription.sql file is (the '123' and '4546' is just there to try and get this to run):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Subscription] (
    [SubscriptionId]             BIGINT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationId]             BIGINT         NOT NULL,
    [SubscriptionName]           NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [ApiKey1]                     CHAR (36)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '123' ,
        [ApiKey2]                     CHAR (36)      NOT NULL DEFAULT '4546' ,
[IsEnabled]                  BIT            CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_Enabled] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive]                   BIT            CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_Active] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
    [AccruedRtusThisMonth]       BIGINT         CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_PendingRtus] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [BilledRtusThisMonth]        BIGINT         CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_PaidRtus] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [OverageChargesThisMonth]    MONEY          CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_OverageChargesThisMonth] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [PricingMode]                TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [PricingPlanId]              BIGINT         NULL,
    [MaxAdditionalMonthlyCharge] MONEY          NOT NULL,
    [XtraAutoTags]               INT            CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_XtraAutoTags_1] DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [EndFreeUse]                 SMALLDATETIME  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_EndFreeUse_1] DEFAULT (getutcdate()) NOT NULL,
    [Created]                    SMALLDATETIME  CONSTRAINT [DF_Subscription_CreatedDate] DEFAULT (getutcdate()) NOT NULL,
    [TS]                         ROWVERSION     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Subscription] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SubscriptionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Subscription_PricingPlan] FOREIGN KEY ([PricingPlanId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PricingPlan] ([PricingPlanId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Subscription_Organization] FOREIGN KEY ([OrganizationId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Organization] ([OrganizationId])
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Subscription_OrganizationId]
    ON [dbo].[Subscription] ([OrganizationId] ASC);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Subscription_ApiKey1]
    ON [dbo].[Subscription]([ApiKey1] ASC);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Subscription_ApiKey2]
    ON [dbo].[Subscription]([ApiKey2] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Subscription_EndFreeUse]
    ON [dbo].[Subscription]([EndFreeUse] ASC);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Subscription_Name]
    ON [dbo].[Subscription]([SubscriptionName] ASC);



GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The primary key',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'SubscriptionId'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'FK to the Organization that owns this credit card',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'OrganizationId'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The key supplied to the engine & AutoTag',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'ApiKey1'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Alternative key. Either can be used.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'ApiKey2'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The customer sets to false to turn this off.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'IsEnabled'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Windward sets to false to force this off.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'IsActive'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'RTUs that have accrued so far this month.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'AccruedRtusThisMonth'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'RTUs that have been paid for so far this month. Includes the RTUs that come with the monthly plan.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'BilledRtusThisMonth'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'How much has accrued in overages so far this month.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'OverageChargesThisMonth'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The maximum allowed to charge for overages each month. Reports are disallowed after hitting this maximum.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'MaxAdditionalMonthlyCharge'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Number of additional AutoTags purchased.',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'XtraAutoTags'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Date that free use (trial) ends',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'EndFreeUse'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'Date this record was created',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'Created'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'The pricing plan on. 1 = bronze, 2 = silver, 3 = gold, 4 = platinum, 255 = custom',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'PricingMode'
GO
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty @name = N'MS_Description',
    @value = N'FK to the pricing plan if a custom plan',
    @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name = N'dbo',
    @level1type = N'TABLE',
    @level1name = N'Subscription',
    @level2type = N'COLUMN',
    @level2name = N'PricingPlanId'
```

Why is it unhappy?

thanks - dave

Comment: Lovely, -2 with no comment as to why...

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Open SSMS and connect to (LocalDb)\ProjectsV13 (replace ProjectsV13 with the name of your DB). In my case the database was in C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\ProjectsV13 and the name comes from the folder.

Once it's open, select the DB in SSMS and delete it. Really simple solution once you know what to do.

BTW - connecting to localhost doesn't give you the local DBs. And just (localdb) doesn't work.

Comment: Your solution to that was deleting the database?

Comment: @MMalke Yep, deleting the local database it created.